# How to get PowerShell to display registry Data values

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

Take the Winlogon registry section, I would like PowerShell to display the Data value for 
DefaultUserName.

This is as far as I have got:

Stage 1

```
get-itemproperty -path "hklm:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\"
```

Stage 2

I can append:

```
-Name DefaultUserName
```

But this won't return a value.

Also other Names, despite being visible in regedit, don't show in PowerShell, for example AutoAdminLogon.

Question: how can make PowerShell display what I can see with regedit?

Comment: Soryy, I had to read that twice. I see the AutoAdminLogon field when I run the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the very same commands on another machine, they worked perfectly, as expected. Thus my original machine must have a faulty registry, or at the least, weird permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the standard command line:

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName
```

Answer (score 2):

even simpler:

```
gp "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\").DefaultUserName
```

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
Get-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\" |% {$_.DefaultUserName}
```

Work for you

Comment: Not return any value
Is |% {$_.DefaultUserName}  
the same as -Name DefaultUsername?

Comment: yes just checking.  check to see if you have permmisons to the key.

Comment: Yes, I have full control permission.

Answer (score 0):

A late followup.

As suggested by Frank, **REG.EXE works fine**.

However a small C function fail to read this specific **DefaultUserName** : the API RegQueryValueExA doesn't return error, but a size of 1 bytes !

Under the same branch, I can read **Shell**.

With REGEDIT.EXE I check the permissions, for both values they are

> Administrators : Full, Users : Read.

OS : Windows 7 home premium - 64 bit

```
DWORD RegGetValueA( HKEY hTree, LPCSTR lpSubKey, LPCSTR lpValueName, LPDWORD lpdwType, LPVOID lpData, LPDWORD lpdwSize )
{
    #define KEY_WOW64_32KEY     0x0200      // on 64-bit Windows should operate on the 32-bit registry view ( HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\... )
    #define KEY_WOW64_64KEY     0x0100      // on 64-bit Windows should operate on the 64-bit registry view
    DWORD   ret, dwAlter = 0;
    HKEY    hKey;

retry:
    ret = RegOpenKeyExA( hTree, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ | dwAlter, &hKey );
    if ( ret != ERROR_SUCCESS )
        return  ret;

    ret = RegQueryValueExA( hKey, lpValueName, NULL, lpdwType, lpData, lpdwSize );
    RegCloseKey( hKey );

    if ( ret != ERROR_SUCCESS && dwAlter == 0 )
    {
        dwAlter = KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
//      printf( "retry... %d\r\n", dwAlter );
        goto retry;
    }

    return  ret;
}
```